# How to convert LWC pages into PDF format?

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, pdf, rerender, web-components

My current requirement is to convert LWC page into PDF format. I tried built in 're-render as PDF' option though VF page.

But it does not look good & i am not able to add Graphs/Charts into it.

Does anyone know to any way to convert LWC/Aura component to PDF format with graphs/chart included?

Please help!!

Comment: @rahulgawale That question doesnt aswer my question!! I too tried rendering using VF page, but thats not what i want. Also I need to include Graphs/Charts in PDF format!!!

Comment: Mohit, as mentioned in that answer not all functionalities of HTML are supported in PDF. As you need to use LWC only, then as of now there is the only way to use third party js libraries.